# How to use an USB to IDE adapter to connect old hard drives to laptop through USB port?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, sata, ide

I bought an USB / SATA / IDE combined adapter. The adapter can connect SATA and IDE hard drives through USB.  Connecting SATA hard drives is not a problem. I have no clue how to place the jumper settings on the IDE hard drives: slave, master or cable select?

Furthermore, the IDE connector on the USB/IDE converter doesn't fit for all my IDE hard drives: on one of the drives 2 pins remains free on the IDE hard drive, they have no corresponding holes on the adapter connector part. Interestingly, in this case I can connect the hard disk to the adapter in two ways: namely, when the two free pins are on the right side of the adapter connector and when they are on the left side. I wonder which is the correct way to connect?

Comment: Usually you'd want the IDE drive jumpers set as Master. As to the drive with extra pins you'd probably do well to find a manual for that drive.

Comment: A photo of both the USB adapter and the HDD with the extra pins would help, also their brands/types.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't take any photo as I don't have a capable mobile phone, nor digital camera at the moment.

Comment: Under no circumstances mention the maker and the model of the drive because that would give the community a chance to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

> I have no clue how to place the jumper settings on the IDE hard drives: slave, master or cable select?

With only a single drive connected, I don't think it matters at all (the purpose of these jumpers is when you have *two* IDE devices on the same cable), but either "Master" or "Cable Select" is typical in this situation.

*(From what I've read, the M/S setting actually has no effect on disk performance, it only serves the same function as e.g. the SCSI ID on parallel-SCSI disks, allowing commands to target either device 0 or device 1.)*

> this case I can connect the hard disk to the adapter in two ways: namely, when the two free pins are on the right side of the adapter connector and when they are on the left side. I wonder which is the correct way to connect?

The standard 40-pin IDE connection always has one "key" pin: there's no pin #20 on the disk, and there's no hole for pin #20 [on the connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGGTc.jpg). So there's only one position where the connector *physically fits* the disk.

<sup>(That is, assuming the adapter isn't the *extremely* cheap kind where the manufacturer didn't block out the hole for pin #20...)</sup>

If you have a *desktop* 3.5" IDE HDD with more pins than that – I have no idea; haven't seen that one yet. But assuming it's standard IDE + proprietary extra stuff, then it should still have the "key pin" in the same position, and the connector should only fit one way.

Laptop 2.5" IDE HDDs do indeed use a 44-pin connector which integrates both IDE and power (see [pinout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEPth.gif)); if the extra 4 pins remain unconnected the disk would have no power. But if I remember correctly, this connector is physically smaller as well (higher density), so a 40-pin adapter made for 3.5" disks again shouldn't even *fit* a 2.5" disk, unless you bend a whole lot of pins.

And even if it does fit, the key pin #20 would only allow the connection at the correct position (unless the adapter doesn't have the #20 correctly blocked out, or unless pin 19 got bent too).

(The cheap Gembird IDE-to-USB adapter that I recently bought has *two* IDE connectors: 40-pin on one side for desktop 3.5" disks; 44-pin on the other side for laptop 2.5" disks.)

Comment: We're doing proper PC archaeology here, but this does ring a bell... Is it the odd IDE drive a  2.5" one?